# Quote by Thurston on the Ricci flow

Tags: reference-request, ricci-flow

I recall seeing a quote by William Thurston where he stated that the Geometrization conjecture was almost certain to be true and predicted that it would be proven by curvature flow methods. I don't remember the exact date, but it was from after Hamilton introduced the Ricci flow but well before Perelman's work. Unfortunately, most of the results for Geometrization and Ricci flow are from 2003 or after.  Does anyone know if the quote I'm referring to actually exists, and if so, where to find it?

There is a quote from Thurston lauding Perelman's work, which suggests that he thought the Ricci flow was a promising approach, but I thought there was one from before as well.

> That the geometrization conjecture is true is not a surprise. That a
> proof like Perelman's could be valid is not a surprise: it has a
> certain rightness and inevitability, long dreamed of by many people
> (including me). What is surprising, wonderful and amazing is that someone – Perelman – succeeded in rigorously analyzing and controlling this process, despite the many hurdles, challenges and potential pitfalls.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think that before Perelman, the Ricci flow method was not considered the most promising. Perhaps @Misha can clarify that. Or you can look at his book Kapovich, Michael Hyperbolic manifolds and discrete groups. Reprint of the 2001 edition. Modern Birkhäuser Classics. Birkhäuser Boston, Ltd., Boston, MA, 2009. xxviii+467 pp. ISBN: 978-0-8176-4912-8

Comment: I think quite a few influential mathematicians were enthusiastic about Ricci flow.  The enthusiasm level really spiked in the mid-90's with Hamilton's work.   I recall Hyam Rubinstein talking about hopes for Ricci flow back then.   But as Mark mentions in his previous comment, it was seen as one of many approaches -- by far the majority of people working on geometrization were working on elements of Thurston's program.

Comment: Before Perelman, I was one of the people who was skeptical that the Thurston conjecture could be proved using the Ricci flow. That in itself means little, but I don't recall anyone telling me what a fool I was. Or telling me that Thurston disagreed with me.

Comment: I've unfortunately forgotten the name of the mathematician, but there was someone else who tried for many years (or even decades) to prove the Poincaré conjecture without the Ricci flow and did not succeed as far as I know. I think they were trying to use some type of discretization procedure which is too naive to prove the conjecture and falls into some of the ''pitfalls of low-dimensional topology'' mentioned by Milnor.

Comment: @HollisWilliams: there are many.  Marshall Cohen has a wonderful lecture giving a complete enumeration up until 1996.

Comment: I seem to remember that J.Milnor, in his overview paper on the Poincare Conjecture, had a chance but didn't even mention Ricci at all. (Is this right?)

Answer (score 16):

Most likely, this is just misremembering (or misattribution).

1. In his math writing Thurston did not make any predictions regarding what approach to the *Geometrization Conjecture* (GC) will be successful. I did not hear him making such predictions in his math lectures (but, of course, I heard only few), and I would be surprised if he did. What Thurston might have said to somebody privately, I do not know.
2. However, Thurston was well aware of the power of the Ricci Flow (RF) and in the early 1980s Thurston did write few pages with a sketch of the proof of the *Orbifold Theorem* which is the  geometrization theorem for orientable irreducible orbifolds with nonempty orbifold locus:

- W. P. Thurston, *Three-manifolds with symmetry*, preprint, Princeton University, 1982, 5 pages.

  One of the steps of the proof was an application of Hamilton's 1982 result on manifolds of positive curvature (proven via RF, of course). A proof of the Orbifold Theorem was given later on in a work by Boileau, Leeb and Porti (broadly speaking, their proof follows Thurston's outline), shortly before appearance of Perelman's preprints. A bit different proof was later given in a work of Cooper, Hodgson and Kerckhoff.  Both proofs use Hamilton's theorem at some point, as Thurston suggested.

3. In the mid 1990s Thurston was developing his own approach to the part of the GC known as the *Hyperbolization Conjecture*, based on analyzing laminations/foliations in 3-manifolds:

- *Three-manifolds, Foliations and Circles, I.* arXiv:[math/9712268](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9712268).

4. In the last chapter of my 2001 book

- *Kapovich, Michael*, Hyperbolic manifolds and discrete groups, Progress in Mathematics (Boston, Mass.). 183. Boston, MA: Birkhäuser. xxv, 467 p. (2001). [ZBL0958.57001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0958.57001).

  I summarized  several known approaches to the GC. Two approaches were differential-geometric (RF and the Mike Anderson's approach), one was via min-volume (a combination of differential and Alexandrov geometry) and one was coarse geometric (to the "hyperbolic part" of the conjecture). At the time, it was quite possible that the GC will be proven in a piece-meal fashion with one proof of the hyperbolization conjecture, another for the Poincare Conjecture and yet another for Spherical Space Forms Conjecture.

5. Regarding Ryan's comment: There was nothing even close to a consensus on the most promising approach to the GC. Hamilton and Yau believed it to be the RF, Mike Anderson had his own approach, Besson, Courtois and Gallot were making progress via the min-volume approach, some people in (or close to) Geometric Group Theory (like myself) believed it was via Cannon's Conjecture (still open) and Coarse Hyperbolization, etc. And there was no such  thing as "Thurston's program" for proving the GC. The closest thing to it was the plan for proving the Orbifold Theorem, but by the 1990s it was clear that this approach will not prove the full GC. In this list of successes one should also add the work of Gabai who in 1990s was proving directly some consequences of the Hyperbolization Conjecture, as well as the work of Tukia, Mess, Gabai, Casson and Jungreis, proving Seifert Conjecture.

Comment: The reference for 3. is https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9712268 . Also, Calegari had some papers towards this approach.

Comment: Great answer. I did not know about the BCG approach, although I knew about their work on minimal volume. Is there an explanation of this approach somewhere or could you sketch it? And is anyone still trying to prove the theorem using an approach different from Ricci flow?

Comment: @DeaneYang: The BCG (or, rather, Gromov's) approach is sketched in my book. Roughly, you impose the lower curvature bound $-1$ and then try to minimize volume in this class of metrics. What BCG proved is that if there is a hyperbolic metric, then it will minimize volume. As for anybody currently trying to reprove GC via an approach different from the RF, I do not know. There was a lot of work on geometric flows in the last 20 years and maybe some of the authors are trying to do this (secretly). But there is very little reward for reproving a known theorem...

Comment: Thank you for the insightful and detailed answer. I suspect I must have misremembered.

Comment: Misha, I would think a different proof that avoids using a geometric heat flow might still be of interest, especially if it involves new and deeper insights into the geometry and topology of 3-manifolds.

Comment: @DeaneYang I have forgotten their name, but there is a mathematician who has spent several decades trying to give a proof of the Poincaré conjecture which does not use a geometric flow (without success, as far as I know).

Comment: @DeaneYang: I do not disagree, but my point is that the current promotion system disincentives such work.

Comment: @HollisWilliams: Many topologists tried to prove the PC (Stallings, Dunwoody, Rourke and Sanderson); Poenaru tried to prove that the universal covering space of a closed contractible 3-manifold is homeomorphic to $R^3$. Casson also thought about the problem. ...

Comment: I do recall Poenaru’s 100 page outline of an outline of a proof of the Poincaré conjecture.

Comment: @HollisWilliams As Misha noted, there were quite a few people who tried to attack the Poincare conjecture. Notably,  John Stallings wrote the memorably titled paper "How Not To Prove The Poincaré Conjecture."

Comment: To be fair, back in those days,almost every differential geometer and topologist was trying in some way to make progress on this. Even I had my own “program”.

Comment: @Misha Just to confirm Hollis Williams's memory, I also remember that not too many years before Perelman's preprints, someone *announced* a proof of the Poincare conjecture. The claim didn't survive very long, but it was long enough that I (whose area of research is far removed from topology) heard about it. The only thing I remember about it was the same thing Hollis Williams already mentioned: It was a highly discretized argument.

Comment: @TimothyChow: I am not sure how I can help you here. Most likely, you are remembering an attempted proof I listed above. Or you remember for instance, a paper by a fellow named Nikitin, which was about 5 page long, dealt with triangulated 3-manifolds and posted on the Arxiv in late 1990s. His "proof" of PC was based on misunderstanding of what it means for a manifold to be simply connected. Or you remember something completely different, say, the 1997 attempt by Resnikov to prove the Virtual Haken Conjecture. Honestly, I have not idea.

Comment: Whitehead had a beautiful attempt at the Poincare Conjecture -- it gave us the Whitehead manifold.

Answer (score 10):

There is a [video of Thurston's talk "A discussion on geometrization"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qzxk8VLqGcI) from May 7, 2001. In the last part of this talk he speaks about possible approaches to proving geometrization.

Starting from [46:55](https://youtu.be/Qzxk8VLqGcI?t=2815) he spends 20 seconds mentioning heat type flows (probably Ricci flow) and says that it might or not work. But then he switches to describing a different approach which he thinks is more robust.

The part of the talk where he starts to speak about future predictions in the sense of proving geometrization starts at [39:32](https://youtu.be/Qzxk8VLqGcI?t=2372).

Comment: Yes, in the video Thurston mostly  talks about his approach to GC using genuine laminations. (There is also a part where the tries to define an analogue of a heat flow on the space of conformal structures on a 3-manifold, but this idea never takes off the ground.)

Answer (score 7):

This 1994 paper by Thurston may or may not be the source you are thinking of, but it is a thoughtful essay that conveys the confidence Thurston had in his conjecture (albeit without referring to curvature flow):

> The full geometrization conjecture is still a conjecture. It has been
> proven for many cases, and is supported by a great deal of computer
> evidence as well, but it has not been proven in generality. I am
> convinced that the general proof will be discovered; I hope before too
> many more years. At that point, proofs of special cases are likely to
> become obsolete.

[On proof and progress in mathematics](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9404236)

Comment: I think this would be more suitable as a comment, rather than an answer.

Comment: Well, it does narrow the time frame , doesn't it? In this 1994 essay Thurston is noncommittal as to the method that will generalize his own proof for Haken manifolds, other than saying that _"It is unlikely that the proof of the general geometrization conjecture will consist of pushing the same proof further."_ So it is likely that any pre-Perelman quote referring to Hamilton's innovation (from the time span 1982-1986) would have to be after 1994 and before 2003.

Comment: Sure, it does narrow the time frame, but comments can do this too, no?